# Can strtol set the second argument to a value not in the string

Tags: c

I'm using `strtol` to parse integers from strings. I intended to use the second argument of `strtol` to determine whether the whole string was parsed as a number. I have code like this (the string will never represent < 1):

```
char digits[32];
char* ptr = token->token;
const size_t tokenLen = token->tokenLen;

//token->token may not be NUL terminated
//copy it to temp buffer to ensure it is
for (size_t k = 0; k < tokenLen; k += 1) {
    digits[k] = ptr[k];
}
digits[tokenLen] = 0;

long index = strtol(digits, &ptr, 10);

if (
    !index || index == LONG_MAX || index >= arr->size
    || (ptr - token->token + 1) != tokenLen
) {
    //Error
} else {
    //All good
}
```

However, this is failing tests because the second argument `ptr` is being set to an address unrelated to my string. I notice that after the call, *ptr is always '\0' (I'm testing against the string `"1"` using gcc-6). I found the following text in the [strtol manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html):

> In particular, if *nptr is not '\0' but **endptr is '\0' on return,
>   the entire string is valid.

I'd like to avoid simply checking that `*ptr == '\0'` because the strings may contain `NUL` characters which would be an error condition that ideally is caught by the

```
(ptr - token->token + 1) != tokenLen
```

check in the `if` statement.

So my question is, can `strtol` set the second argument to an address not contained in the string, and is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: The second argument to your `strtol` is not `ptr`, but `&ptr`!

Comment: "because the strings may contain NUL characters". Not sure what you mean by that: a string *ends* with a NUL character. What do you mean by 'may *contain*'?

Comment: @Evert The strings are fragments of JSON Pointer syntax, which allows any Unicode char in the grammar (see [RFC 6901](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6901#section-3)). So I don't rely on the strings being NUL terminated in memory, but keep track of their lengths.

Comment: A C string is by definition terminated by the first `'\0'` character, and `strtol` will ignore anything past it. It *can't* process data with embedded null characters.

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't expect `strtol` to process data with embedded NUL, which is why I check to see if all the data was consumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing a copy of the string to to `strtol`, so the value of `ptr` will be in the copy, not the original.  You're also adding 1 to the length, which is incorrect.  Just change:

```
(ptr - token->token + 1) != tokenLen
```

to:

```
ptr - digits != tokenLen
```

Answer (score 2):

The value set into `ptr` will be related to the buffer passed as the first argument, i.e. `digits`. Since `token->token` does *not* point into `digits` array, the following expression is invalid:

```
(ptr - token->token + 1)
```

Assuming that `tokenLen` includes null terminator, you need to compute

```
(ptr - digits) // Do not add 1
```

in order to obtain the number of characters consumed by `strtol`.

To answer your question, no `strtol` is not allowed to set `*ptr` to values outside of the string represented by the first argument.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The length given here will be 1 too high.

Comment: @TomKarzes I think OP includes null terminator in the length of the token stored in `tokenLen` field of his token struct. Otherwise he'd be using `strlen`.

Comment: Look at the loop that copies it to `digits`.  It first copies `tokenLen` characters.  Then after the loop it stores `0` at index `tokenLen`.  This implies that `tokenLen` does *not* include the terminating null byte.

Comment: Adding 1 was a mistake on my part. I didn't catch it until the pointer problem was resolved first.